# Warning: Constant WP_DEBUG already defined

Tags: wp-cli, wp-debug

- PHP 8.1.17
- WP-CLI 2.7.1
- WP set up as multisite network

Adding the following line to `wp-config.php` (line 107)…

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

…causes `wp-cli` to report the following…

```
$ wp plugin list

Warning: Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.
php(1296) : eval()'d code on line 106
```

…and the web server to report the following:

```
PHP Error: PHP Warning: Constant WP_DEBUG already defined in /path/to/wp-config.php on line 107
```

I’ve only defined `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php`. Where might the other definition of this constant be?

Comment: Have you tried disabling themes and plugins to see if the issue goes away?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, I deactivated plugins and theme, one at a time, checking after every deactivation. The wp-cli warning persisted, even with all of them deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't know that this was already in `wp-config.php`:

```
if (!defined('WP_DEBUG')) {
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
}
```

So the `define` statement I added was indeed redundant. Duh!